# latexmk: Failure in some part of making files when adding bibliography

Tags: bibtex, latexmk, atom

I am using latex in Atom and I'm trying to add bibliography. I've created file `biblio.bib`, which looks as follows:

```
@article{bollen,
Author = {J. Bollen and H. Mao and X.J. Zeng},
Date-Added = {2020-04-18 14:38:26 +0300},
Date-Modified = {2020-04-18 14:38:43 +0300},
Journal = {Journal of Computational Science},
Month = {March},
Number = {1},
Pages = {1-8},
Title = {Twitter mood predicts the stock market},
Url = {https://arxiv.org/pdf/1010.3003.pdf},
Volume = {2},
Year = {2011},
Eprint = {1010.3003},
Primaryclass = {cs.CE},
Bdsk-Url-1 = {https://arxiv.org/pdf/1010.3003.pdf}}

@webpage{pwc2,
Date-Added = {2020-04-18 14:24:34 +0300},
Date-Modified = {2020-04-18 14:24:56 +0300},
Title = {Papers With Code},
Url = {https://paperswithcode.com/area/natural-language-processing},
Bdsk-Url-1 = {https://paperswithcode.com/area/natural-language-processing}}
```

When there is no bibliography, everything compiles perfectly. However, when I add it with two following commands: `\bibliographystyle{utf8gost705u} \bibliography{biblio}`, I get the error `latexmk: Failure in some part of making files` and no pdf file is produced. Could someone tell me where the potential problem can be.

Comment: The error message you quote is not one that is from the distributed version of latexmk.  The only place in the latexmk source code that the string `Failure in some part of making files` appears is in a comment, so you should not see an error message containing this string.  Please check that you have quoted it right.  You should first look through the screen output for more informative error messages.  You may find it in latexmk's summary near the end.  If not examine the rest of the screen output to see what errors were reported by the programs invoked by latexmk.

Comment: And if that doesn't help enough, you should include the screen output in your question, so we can see what was going on.